# Python import gdata Google Apps Engine: Course Builder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, google-provisioning-api

I'm working with Google Course Builder and I'm trying to import the GData library so that I can utilize the provisioning API to add members to google groups as they register for the course.

Inside of `utils.py` of course builder lies the functions for registration.

The problem is when I add `import gdata.apps.groups.client` and then run the server locally, the browser returns an internal server error 500.

Obviously, I'm missing a step here, but where do I put the GData folder if not in my site-packages folder? I've copied it into all of the directories in course builder with no success.

Here is the *original* import section in the `utils.py` file:

```
import logging, urlparse, webapp2, jinja2
from models.models import Student, Unit, MemcacheManager
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models.utils import getAllScores
```

Any help is ***greatly*** appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting gdata and atom from the [gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list) in the same folder as your app.yaml (root of your AppEngine app).

Comment: Jay, you've been awesome.  No idea I needed atom in there. Thank you for this.  Now I'm running into a very weird issue tho: "File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\httplib.py", line 506, in getresponse
    'An error occured while connecting to the server: %s' % e)
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin Error: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed"  - Any ideas?

Comment: You're using ClientLogin with AppEngine? Bad idea, ClientLogin is deprecated. Use OAuth2 authentication.